# Travelling outside the UK without a passport

Tags: uk, passports, uk-citizens, ukraine, biometric-passports

I've read all of the relevant questions on here regarding travelling outside the UK without a passport.

As I understand, I, as a British Citizen after naturalisation, can travel to and stay in any EU country without a passport - as long as I have a Biometric Residence Permit. Is that correct?

I wish to travel to Ukraine immediately but do not understand if I can enter with a Biometric Residence Permit only - or if I need a passport first.
And whether I would be able to get back.

I do not hold any other nationality. As a former Ukrainian citizen, my citizenship was revoked automatically as soon as I received my British citizenship.
I have never owned an adult Ukrainian passport.

Please can someone advise?

Comment: I think you may be a bit confused. Only foreign residents of the UK hold BRPs. British citizens cannot have one. As British citizens, our only travel document is our passport. Unlike other European countries, we don’t have any kind of ID card.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Ukraine is not in the EU https://www.gov.uk/eu-eea according to Timatic you need a passport to enter https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

BRPs must be returned to the Home Office within 5 working days of getting your certificate of British citizenship, you can be fined up to £1,000 for not doing so. You cannot enter the UK using your BRP or certificate of British citizenship. https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-indefinite-leave-to-remain/after-you-get-your-certificate

Answer (score 4):

> As a former Ukrainian citizen, my citizenship was revoked automatically as soon as I received my British citizenship.

That's not true. Ukraine does not revoke citizenship automatically.

You should request for renouncing of your Ukrainian citizenship in the Embassy of Ukraine in the UK.
If you did not request it, then you are treated as a citizen of Ukraine.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the Brexit situation is still extremely unsettled as of today (March 23th 2019) and that a "hard Brexit" remains a possibility.

While both sides proclaim that there will be generous solutions for UK and EU27 citizens, you should expect that exceptions and special cases may disappear. A proper passport is a good idea.

Comment: Unless traveling through EU27 that is not the major issue as Ukraine, where the OP wants to travel to, is not part of EU28 (or EU27 for that matter).

Comment: @Ghanima, the OP talked about "any EU country" as well. I guessed he wants to pass e.g. the Ukraine/Polish land border. They might want to stamp his passport on the Polish side.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that you must return your BRP after naturalisation. It's no longer valid and you must not use it.

For international travel you will need a valid travel document. Also please be aware that the UK typically wants UK nationals to use a UK passport when they enter the country.